# Is It possible to change New Project creation level using WizardNewProjectCreationPage??

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wizard

To create a *New Project* i am using **WizardNewProjectCreationPage** which creates a new project at root level.
Is it possible by any way to change that level.

For *example* there is already a root level folder in *Project Explorer* which contain some folders in it.Now i want when i *right click* on any of these folder and *Add* say *New->Component*.
On Component i have coded *WizardNewProjectCreationPage*,as i need the same functionality which *ProjectCreationPage* do .

But now i want this project should be added **under the folder i right clicked** and added component and so not on the root level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do this. Eclipse projects can only be in the workspace root.

If you just want to create files and folders you can look at `BasicNewFileResourceWizard`, `BasicNewFolderResourceWizard`, `WizardNewFileCreationPage` and `WizardNewFolderMainPage`.

Comment: What other way i can do this, i dont want it to be called as a new project .i just want when i add component it adds some a folder with some files to the level i add it .Please if u  can suggest something.

Comment: Added some of the other wizards and wizard pages you can use